# copyToLocal is not copying the file local to DataNode

Tags: hadoop

```
I am doing as below
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://IP:PORT"), context.getConfiguration());

            path = new Path("/AAP");
            fsOutStream = fs.create(path);
            // read this file into InputStream
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(value.getBytes());

            IOUtils.copyBytes(inputStream, fsOutStream, context.getConfiguration());  //After this step a new folder AAP is available on HDFS

            //Problem in below step
            fs.copyToLocalFile(path, new Path("/xyz")); //After this step i am expecting that a folder local to DataNode with name "xyz" should be available but its not
```

Note: I have just one DataNode and MapRed is running successfully

Could someone please suggest as what might be the issue?

Comment: You see no errors? Are you specifying an absolute path for the destination local file?

Comment: It would help to see your actual new Path()

Comment: xyz is not already present on local DataNode machine i have just choosen that randomly , just to check copy part functionality then i tried to search that by command  find / -type d -iname 'xyz', however no such directory exists

Comment: Do you see some errors?

Comment: sorry , you mean errors on jobtracker url

Comment: Errors - are some exceptions thrown when you executed your code? How are you executing it anyway?

Comment: no exception is coming . I am executing this with Hadoop Jar command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check:

Do you have rights to write to the root directory?

Try with a complete URL: `fs.copyToLocalFile(path, new Path("file:///home/hadoop/xyz"));`